# Problem with pppoe connection (Ubuntu 18.04)!

Tags: 18.04, connection, download-speed, pppoe, dsl

I'm having a problem with pppoe connection, the modem is connected directly to the computer(without the router), i use pppoeconf to connect, but when i connect the speed is much slower that it should be, and it drops all the time, it didn't happen when i had the router, or when using windows 10.

thanks!

Comment: What is your modem type, your provider and your `pppoeconf` configuration?

Comment: My modem is a Huawai SmartAX MT880, I live in Brazil so my isp is Vivo, and in the pppoeconf i just said yes to everything and entered with my isp login and username.